Markov Chains where people can come and go?
Suppose I have the following 4 state Markov Chain:

In this Markov Chain, individuals can enter and exit the system:

Suppose each day, I have the total number of people that are in S1, S2, S3, S4 (I do not have access to how many people entered and exited). This information looks something like this (note: I do not have access to individual entries or individual exits either):
 Day S1 S2 S3 S4
   1 31 15 41 31
   2 79 32 47 30
   3 51  7 90 64
   4 14  9 60 99
   5 67 41 95 14
   6 42 74 16 93
   7 50 23 94 96
   8 43 27  6 71
   9 14 60 72 67
  10 25 53 86 23

Problem: I am trying to estimate the transition matrix for this "open" Markov Chain
$$\hat{P} =
\begin{bmatrix}
\hat{p}{11} & \hat{p}{12} & \hat{p}{13} & \hat{p}{14} \
\hat{p}{21} & \hat{p}{22} & \hat{p}{23} & \hat{p}{24} \
\hat{p}{31} & \hat{p}{32} & \hat{p}{33} & \hat{p}{34} \
\hat{p}{41} & \hat{p}{42} & \hat{p}{43} & \hat{p}{44}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Normally, this would have been a pretty easy thing to do (i.e. use the Multinomial Distribution MLE and take the ratio of all transitions from one to state to all other states). However, in this case, I am not sure how to approach this problem due to the fact that individuals can enter and exit the system.
Currently, I was thinking that perhaps the EM Algorithm might be useful since there are latent variables in this problem?
I tried to define:
$$n_t(i) = \text{number of individuals in state } i \text{ on day } t$$
$$e_t(i) = \text{expected number of entries to state } i \text{ on day } t$$
$$x_t(i) = \text{expected number of exits from state } i \text{ on day } t$$
$$x_t(i) = \text{expected number of exits from state } i \text{ on day } t$$
$$p_{ix} = \text{ the probability of exiting from state} t$$
$$m_t(i,j) = \text{expected number of transitions from state } i \text{ to } j \text{ between days } t \text{ and } t+1$$
But I am not sure how to continue.
Can someone please help me continue working on this problem?
Code for diagrammes:

Is this a discrete time process where each day represents a single time step?

@ DrJ : thank you for answering .for simplicity, lets say its discrete.

I believe there are 2 approaches, depending on what is meant in your application problem by "Entry" and "Exit":
Case 1. "Entry" and "Exit" are out-of/into the same pool. Then you can denote this common pool by "Environment", or a new "E" state for short. This case can now be analyzed as a closed system, from which a standard Markov chain stochastic matrix can be estimated in full. In this case, it is easy to estimate the number of elements within the new "E" state from all the data you have at your disposal: The maximum of the sums over rows in your dataset gives an estimate of the total number of elements in the closed system; Then, all transition probabilities can be estimated, including the ones out-of and into the "E" state.
Case 2. "Entry" and "Exit" are distinct separate states. Then you have a Birth-Death process in the Queueing theory sense, where the "births" do not come from the pool of "dead" elements, i.e., you have two new states: "B" (for births) and "D" (for deaths). This case can now be analyzed as a closed system, from which a standard Markov chain stochastic matrix can be estimated in full, but this case is more difficult to estimate. The simplest analysis can assume an M/M/1 queue, where all the "S" states are conceptually temporarily grouped together as the "queue" whose internals are "opaque" as a 1st stage of analysis. Then, at this 1st analysis stage, you can still use the "common environment" ("E") concept from Case 1 to estimate the combined number of births and deaths $=$ the combined number of elements going into Entry and coming out of Exit at each time step. But then you will need some kind of domain knowledge (from your application problem) to estimate the average ratio between birth and death rates, i.e., between $\lambda$ and $\mu$. For example, in the dataset you provided, each row is a successive day (time step), so we can observe if the total number of elements in the totality of "S" states increases over time or decreases over time: If it increases over time, then birth rate > death rate ($\lambda \gt \mu$); If it decreases, then birth rate < death rate ($\lambda \lt \mu$). Once you have adequately estimated $\lambda$ and $\mu$ separately, you again have a closed system, from which a standard Markov chain stochastic matrix can be estimated in full.

Thank you so much! Do you think your logic can be applied to this question? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4970399/markov-chains-with-aggregate-data

@farrow90 The problem in the other question you've just linked, is that data from some time steps is missing, i.e., the system as a whole is not fully observable. I'll have to think how to estimate in that case; obviously, assuming it's possible, the estimation results will be less accurate than in the case in this question.
