Markov Chains with Aggregate Data?
I have the following Markov Chain:

Suppose I have data from this Markov Chain - I only observe the total population of S1 and S2 at irregular time intervals (i.e. transitions can happen at any time, but I only have the ability to observe the system at limited time points):
 time s1_population s2_population
    7          1000             0
    9           907            93
   14           829           171
   25           770           230
   26           732           268
   31           705           295
   36           702           298
   42           688           312
   43           688           312
   50           675           325
   51           668           332
   57           675           325
   67           661           339
   69           655           345
   72           651           349
   79           669           331
   87           676           324
   90           689           311
   95           664           336
   97           652           348

Goal: I am trying to estimate the transition matrix
$$
\hat{P} = \begin{bmatrix}
\hat{p}{11} & \hat{p}{12} \
\hat{p}{21} & \hat{p}{22}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
In the standard case, this would have been easy - if we had individual paths taken by each patient at regular times, we could just use the standard maximum likelihood estimator.
However in this case, I am not sure how to proceed. I thought that perhaps using a Continuous Time Markov Chain could be a starting point? Here is what I tried:

Define the generator matrix Q for our two-state system:
$$
Q = \begin{bmatrix}
-q_{12} & q_{12} \\
q_{21} & -q_{21}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Where $q_{ij}$ represents the rate of transition from state i to state j.
The transition probability matrix P(t) for a time interval t is related to Q by (solving Kolmogorov):
$$
P(t) = e^{Qt}
$$
Perhaps we can still use Maximum Likelihood Estimation to estimate the transition rates? The likelihood function can be written
$$
L(Q) = \prod_{k=1}^{n} P(t_k - t_{k-1})_{ij}^{n_{ij}(k)}
$$
Where $n_{ij}(k)$ is the number of transitions from state i to state j between time $t_{k-1}$ and $t_k$.
Next, we need to maximize the log-likelihood:
$$
\log L(Q) = \sum_{k=1}^{n} \sum_{i,j} n_{ij}(k) \log P(t_k - t_{k-1})_{ij}
$$
Since we only have aggregate data, we need to estimate the number of transitions. Intuitively, I thought of writing:
$$
n_{ij}(k) \approx \frac{s_i(t_{k-1}) \cdot s_j(t_k)}{\sum_l s_l(t_k)}
$$
Where $s_i(t)$ is the population in state i at time t.

Am I on the right track?

Thanks for the edits Alex! :)

any ideas about this problem Alex?

Just a few cents. If the population is large, you have something like $s(n+k) = P^{n} s(k)$. Now, consider $s(n+k) s(k)^{\top} = P^n s(k)s(k)^{\top}$. Take the mean on both sides of the equation (you should consider all samples that are spaced by $n$): $E[s(n+k) s(n)^{\top}] = P^n E[s(k)s(k)^{\top}]$ $(\star)$. Call $R_0(k) = E[s(k)s(k)^{\top}]$ as the correlation matrix at the instant $k$ and $R_n(k) = E[s(n+k)s(k)^{\top}]$ as the $n$-lag correlation matrix. Then, in view of equation $(\star)$, an estimate could be $\widehat{P} = (R_n R_0^{-1})^{1/n}$. Hope it helps.

thank you Augusto ....
